# Не могу получить данные из формы и вывести в консоль

Tags: javascript, html, form

Есть маленикий кусок html, к которому прикреплен отдельным файлом js. Пробовала alert() и console.log но нет никакого результата. В чем проблема?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jstest.js">
     </head>

      <body>
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="click">
        </form>
      </body>

     </html>
      <script>
        var form = document.getElementById('#form').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('#name').value;
        var name = document.getElementById('#age').value;
        var button  = document.getElementById('#button');
        button.onclick=func();
        function func(){
          if (age==10){
           alert("You wrote 10");
        }
        else{alert("You wrote something else");
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Чтобы добавить js я добавила его ниже с помощью тэга <script> . в реальности js просто прикреплен с помощью <link>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пройдёмся по-порядку:

- Когда вы используете `document.getElementById`, то при передаче аргумента не надо писать `#`. Это надо писать если вы используете `document.querySelector`. Когда вы пишите `#some-id` при вызове `document.getElementById`, то он ищет не `id=some-id`, а ищет `id=#some-id`
- Если вам надо повесить событие на сабмит формы, то не надо слушать событие `click` на кнопке `sumbit` (не то что невозможно, но лучше не стоит), вместо этого вешайте слушателя на событие `submit` у формы. Так вы с помощью `e.preventDefault()` сможете предотвратить перезагрузку страницы, после `submit`-а
- Больше не нужно писать лишний код для того чтобы достать значения полей у формы. Достаточно передать компоненту `form` в [new FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) и он за вас сделает всю грязную работу. Главное не забыть проставить аттрибут `name` у инпутов, потому что значения вы будете доставать именно по ним
- При взятии значения из инпута вы получите строку, даже если ввели число. Потому очень важно об этом помнить и приводить данные к тому типу, который вам нужен

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jstest.js">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameValue">
    <input type="text" id="ageInput" name="ageValue">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="click">
  </form>

  <script>
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      const formData = new FormData(form);
      const age = formData.get('ageValue');
      
      console.log(`typeof ${age} is ${typeof age}`);
      
      checkAge(Number(age));
    })

    function checkAge(age) {
      if (age === 10) {
        console.log("You wrote 10");
      } else {
        console.log("You wrote something else");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за содержательный ответ, очень помогло!

Comment: @ViktorijaPopova Всегда пожалуйста! Если ответ вам помог, то не забудьте пожалуйста принять его (поставить зелёную галочку) - это будет лучшим выражением вашей благодарности, на этой платформе :)